# Conexion a SQLExpress universal

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buen día,

he creado un software,que necesita conectarse a una base de datos en SQL Server express para funcionar. Con niveles de administrador, nunca ha habido problemas.

el problema es cuando el programa lo quiere ejecutar un usuario, el programa trata de conectarse con su usuario a la base de datos, por lo cual falla.
esta es mi conexion en el APP.config

```
<add name="MainModel" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial catalog=AppQR;User Id=sa;Password=sa;integrated security=True;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

y esta es mi base de datos en SQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al ejecutar con usuario, la instrucción localhost indentifica el usuario, y como lo identifica el usuario, no se conecta correctamente a la base de datos en sql. ¿de que manera puedo generalizar la conexion, para que no haya ese problema de administrador y usuario convencional? y definirlo manualmente en cada computadora no es opcion, debido a que el software se ocupara en muchas computadoras.

Comment: Creo que no entendi bien, pero podrias intentar entrar con el usuario sa y la contraseña que pones en tu app.config, o si no lo tienes habilitado el usuario sa, entrar a SQL Server y activarlo para poder usar el usuario

Comment: en esa parte no tengo problema. En una computadora, el administrador instala el software, y monta la base de datos sin ningun problema.en esa misma computadora, hay otros usuarios, con permisos normales. el administrador en su sesion, puede abrir el problema, porque se conecta correctamente al SQL. el problema es cuando el usuario convencional quiere abrir ese mismo programa, el programa quiere conectarse con usuario/sqlexpress en vez de nombredecomputadora/sqlexpress.

Comment: Muy bien, creo que entiendo

<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConnStringDb1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

Intenta usar esto en tu ConnectionString

Comment: la cuestion es que la conexion sql, sera en un servidor express, y todas las computadoras utilizaran el express. el problema es que necesito que no importa el tipo de usuario, el programa pueda utilizarse y conectarse a la base de datos. si es adminsitrador, no hay problema, pero si es usuario comun, la conexion no se efectua y falla el programa.

Comment: ¿SQL express se instalara localmente en cada computadora que va a utilizar el software o todas las PC's que usan el software acceden a un servidor donde esta la DB?

Comment: sql express se instalara localmente en cada computadora. el usuario con permisos de administrador instala el programa y lo ejecuta sin problema. el usuario comun (sin permisos de administrador)  ejecuta el programa, en la misma maquina, y el programa falla, ya que su localhost (no entiendo porque) es diferente y no encuentra la base de datos.

Comment: Tu cadena de conexión es el problema. Es errónea, porque dice que la autenticación es de Windows: Integrated Security=true significa, que te autenticas como el usuario de windows. Por eso los administradores, les va ok, y a los usuarios normales les falla. Nota Importante. Nunca uses el usuario sa para una aplicación. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax

Comment: @Javifer2 gracias por tu respuesta, ese era mi error, a pesar de tener las claves, por ese integrated security nunca mandaba los logins correctos de sa.
se que no deberian usarse los de sa, pero el usuario final quiere hacer la instalacion final, y solamente contactarnos si hay fallos, y no tienen experiencia al usar SQL. a pesar de mandar un manual de instalacion y configuracion,hemos detectado que no lo usan.

Answer (score 0):

Segun entendi por tu último comentario parece ser que el problema son los accesos, intenta agregando los usuarios locales para que puedan acceder al motor de base de datos, tendrías que utilizar sql server management (u otro SGDB) y acceder con el sa:

1. Seguridad (Security)
2. Inicios de Sesión (Logins)
3. Clic derecho, Nuevo inicio de sesión (New login)
4. Debe estar marcada la opción  de autenticación de windows (Windows authentication)
5. Le das en buscar (Search) y buscas el usuario, si es local lo dejas con el nombre del equipo, sino ahi mismo tienes la opción de buscar en Active Directory
6. Añade el usuario y luego dale permisos para acceder a la db de tu sistema en Asignación de usuarios (User Mapping)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva, saludos.